# Is there a way to get the most searched words on the internet recently?

Tags: search-engine

I'd like to get a big list (say 1,000 or more) of word phrases that people search for on the internet recently (anything from the most recent month or week or day is ok). Results from Google or any of the bigger search sites would be okay. And is there a way to do this programmatically? Python would be first choice, shell scripts works too. Thanks!

Bonus points for historical results too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.google.com/trends

google is pretty data friendly

they even provide rss feeds

http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly

Yes, It's python friendly with API and easy_install to boot!

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyGTrends/0.81

Answer (score 2):

Along with what TelsaBoil post, Google Insights looks to give historical results too

http://www.google.com/insights/search/

Comment: This is a great feature of google i've never heard about. Combine this with your adwords hunting. I dislike google's adwords interface.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check this ones:

http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends

http://www.google.com/trends/hottrends/atom/hourly  [RSS Hourly Feed]

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyGTrends/0.81 [Python Google Trends Information Retrieval]